# How to point a subdomain to a folder on different host with another domain

Tags: dns, hosting

I have 2 domains: mydomain.com & myotherdomain.com. 
I have uploaded some files to my server to some folder and I can access them by: mydomain.com/path/folder 
How can I make a subdomain of myotherdomain.com - example.myotherdomain.com - to point to mydomain.com/path/folder? 
I'm using cPanel, do I have to configure anything there? I tried Addon domain and subdomain. I guess I have to add DNS records but I don't really understand how it works.
Any help much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider following simple case scenario to redirect sub-domain of one domain to another main domain.

[1] Domain A is hosted

[2] Domain B is hosted.

[3] Domain B is having sub-domain C which will automatically lands where domain B is hosted.So donot change any NS record for sub domain C.

[4] Now write redirection rule in .htaccess file for sub domain C which leads to domain A

Comment: Is this the only way? unfortunately Domain B (and its subdomain C) are linked to google sites platform, can't have .htaccess file there

Comment: then create CNAME record for Domain A on sub domain C.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what worked for me was -

In cPanel:

1. Add myotherdomain.com to the hosting
2. Add example.myotherdomain.com as a subdomain of myotherdomain.com and state the desirable folder.

DNS Zones management:

3. Create NS record for example.myotherdomain.com